# Customizing my discussion board list (remove filters & remove "Best Reply” link) cannot find a suitable way to do this

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, list, list-view, xslt

I spend the whole day trying to do things which seems straight forward , but cannot find a suitable solution. Now I added a discussion board app, and I though that I will have regular list views found in SP lists where I can add/edit/delete list views. But seem inside the discussion board  I will be dealing with filters inside a single view as follow:-

[image]

Where there are filters such as recent, my discussions, What’s hot , etc…

- First question. I want to hide all the filters except the “Recent” & “My discussion”. So how I can do so ? From where I can access this ? I have an on-primise SP so I am open to all solutions?
- Second question. Seems by default the discussion creator can select certain reply as the “Best Reply”, but our client ask to disable this. So  I cannot find any option to disable this inside the list settings.. so how I can hide the “Best Reply” link ?
  Thanks in advance for any help and support..

Answer (score 3):

Add content editor web part, hide layout in settings

```
<style> 
    .ms-ellipsis-icon {display:none;}
    .ms-pivotControl-surfacedOpt, .ms-pivotControl-overflowDot {display:none;}      
</style>
```